# Android Firebase : Cannot figure out how to use GSON to make pojo

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, gson

I have the following kind of `JSON` that I get from Firebase:

```
{
    "customID": {
        "date": "13-9-2019",
        "desc": "describes me",
        "eventType": "(event) other",
        "pricerange": "1-1",
        "shape": "round",
        "weight": "7"
    },
    "customID1": {
        "date": "guddu",
        "desc": "desc",
        "eventType": "eventype",
        "pricerange": "1-2",
        "shape": "roundd",
        "weight": 4
    }
}
```

When I use these two as a template I saw that there are two classes `CustomID` and `CustomID1`. So how do I make the POJO with GSON that can take changing class names?

Comment: this seems like a hacky response from firebase. You may want to fix firebase to not return objects with custom keys every time. Sure, there are ways to solve this on the client side, the real issue in on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create a class which changes it's name, a simple class with the given arguments would do the trick. Just think about it, if you provide the required arguments, the class will work.

However, if you want to parse multiple instances consider using a hashmap at parsing.

Example for class:

```
data class CustomId(val date: String?, val desc:String?...
```

(Just to be simple I wrote a data class instead of a regular class but I hope you got the point.)

However, if you want to parse a list, with customIDs a class like

> class ListOfIds{
>       val listOfCustomIds = HashMap() }

Answer (score 0):

> when I use these two as a template I saw that there are two classes CustomID and CustomID1

No, there **not** two classes, there two different objects of the same class. If you want to create that class, please see the following lines of code:

```
public class Event {
    private String date, desc, eventType, pricerange, shape, weight;

    public Event() {}

    public Event(String date, String desc, String eventType, String pricerange, String shape, String weight) {
        this.date = date;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.pricerange = pricerange;
        this.shape = shape;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getDate() { return date; }

    public String getDesc() { return desc; }

    public String getEventType() { return eventType; }

    public String getPricerange() { return pricerange; }

    public String getShape() { return shape; }

    public String getWeight() { return weight; }
}
```

That's the way in which you create private fields with public getters and that's the way in which you can simply create public fieds:

```
public class Event {
    public String date, desc, eventType, pricerange, shape, weight;
}
```

In whis case you get/set values directly on public fields.